# Confusion when defining a list of array refs as constant

Tags: arrays, list, perl, reference, constants

In some Perl code I'm doing some low-level coding accessing Perl constants that are lists, like this:

> use constant LIST => ()

As Perl constants are actually implemented as functions, I'm trying to get the value via the symbol table as `${__PACKAGE__.'::'}{LIST}->()`.

The confusing part is that sometimes Perl dies with:

> Not a CODE reference at ...

Running a debugger test session I got the impression that the constant uses a different representation if the list has only one element:

```perl-db
  DB<18> use constant TEST => (['status', 1, undef],)

  DB<19> x ${__PACKAGE__ . '::'}{TEST}
0  REF(0x2871fc8)
   -> ARRAY(0x2a914f0)
         0  'status'
         1  1
         2  undef
  DB<20> x TEST
0  ARRAY(0x2a914f0)
   0  'status'
   1  1
   2  undef
  DB<21> use constant TEST2 => (['status', 1, undef], ['something', 2, undef])

  DB<22> x ${__PACKAGE__ . '::'}{TEST2}
0  *Auth::Verifier::TEST2
  DB<23> x TEST2
0  ARRAY(0x2a092d8)
   0  'status'
   1  1
   2  undef
1  ARRAY(0x2a91808)
   0  'something'
   1  2
   2  undef
  DB<24> x ${__PACKAGE__ . '::'}{TEST2}->()
0  ARRAY(0x2a092d8)
   0  'status'
   1  1
   2  undef
1  ARRAY(0x2a91808)
   0  'something'
   1  2
   2  undef
  DB<25> x ${__PACKAGE__ . '::'}{TEST}->()
Not a CODE reference at (eval 35)[/usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/perl5db.pl:732] line 2.
  DB<26>
```

Is there a way to force constants to be functions?
I'm using an older Perl (perl5 (revision 5 version 18 subversion 2)).

### Update

It seems that regular functions (compared to `use constant`) doe not have such "optimization" that https://stackoverflow.com/a/76407240/6607497 suggests:

```perl-db
  DB<22> sub f3 { ([1]) }

  DB<23> sub f4 { ([1],[2]) }

  DB<24> x ${main::}{f3}->()
0  ARRAY(0x1413670)
   0  1
  DB<25> x ${main::}{f4}->()
0  ARRAY(0x1413508)
   0  1
1  ARRAY(0x13f9720)
   0  2
  DB<26> x ${main::}{f3}
0  *main::f3
  DB<28> x ${main::}{f4}
0  *main::f4
```

Here all "constants" are actual functions.
also note that adding a `()` prototype does not change that (see "man perlsub" on constants for details).

Comment: Is this an X-Y problem? You seem to be making a lot of work for yourself. Why not simply define your constants as array references (e.g. `use constant TEST => [ [ status => 1 ] ];` and then access them as (say) `TEST->[0][0]`, instead of jumping through all the symbolic-dereference hoops?

Comment: It's historic: I started using lists instead of array references; changing it now would trigger *a lot* of changes to the existing code. But still I think my question is a valid one.

Comment: I feel your pain. Be aware that under Perl 5.36.1 your example involving `TEST2` (duplicated by cut-and-paste) also produces `Not a code reference ...`, so your code base will be screwed if you upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

- `\&TEST` will return a sub.
- `&TEST()` will call it as a sub.

So they are effectively subs. You're simply not seeing them in the symbol table as subs.

A while back, the symbol table was optimized to save space. I don't know all the details, but I believe symbols associated with a only one variable are replaced with a reference to that variable. Since most entries contains only a single variable (usually a sub), this saves a lot of memory. Code visiting navigating the symbol table will need to take these changes into consideration.

Comment: Would you elaborate a bit: How would such code look like that considers the different representations? Are there really only two possibilities (*function* or *REF*), or is it "subject to change at any time"? Or is there some pragma disabling that kind of optimization?

Comment: I don't know. You asked how to obtain the ref, and the answer is that you can use `\&`.  /// It already changed once, so it could definitely change again. /// Not that I know of.

Comment: The actual question was: "*Is there a way to force constants to be functions?*"

Comment: They always are, as stated in the answer.

Comment: Well, when accessing the constants via the symbol table they are *not* (thus my question).

Comment: So you asked how to obtain the ref, and the answer is that you can use `\&`.

Comment: ` \&{${main::}{TEST}}` still complains with "Not a subroutine reference ...".

Comment: That's not how you get a sub ref. The symbol is `TEST`, so `\&TEST` or `\&{ "TEST" }`

Comment: But how can I access it via the symbol table? `\&{__PACKAGE__ . '::'}{TEST}` does not work ("syntax error").

Comment: `\&{ __PACKAGE__ . '::' . 'TEST' }`

Comment: As the original question was about accessing the object via the symbol table, you should update your answer to take that into account, because the comments following showed that the answer is not as clear as you might have thought.

Answer (score 0):

The magic what happens can be found in constant.pm:

```perl
# ...
        {
# ...
            if ($multiple || @_ == 1) {
                my $scalar = $multiple ? $constants->{$name} : $_[0];

# ...
                # The constant serves to optimise this entire block out on
                # 5.8 and earlier.
                if (_CAN_PCS && $symtab && !exists $symtab->{$name}) {
# ...
                    Internals::SvREADONLY($scalar, 1);
                    $symtab->{$name} = \$scalar;
                    ++$flush_mro;
                } else {
                    *$full_name = sub () { $scalar };
                }
            } elsif (@_) {
                my @list = @_;
                *$full_name = sub () { @list };
            } else {
                *$full_name = sub () { };
            }
        }
# ...
```

So when there is only a single value, no function will be created, but the reference of the value will be used instead.

The reason ("*Storing a reference to a constant value in a symbol table is equivalent to a full typeglob referencing a constant subroutine, but using about 400 bytes less memory.*") is explained in [Constant subroutines](https://metacpan.org/release/NWCLARK/perl-5.8.9/view/pod/perl589delta.pod#Constant-subroutines) on metacpan.org as part of Perl 5.8.9 changes.

However it seems that "is equivalent" means the Perl interpreter handles the difference internally.